# Socket io and react problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I'm making a connection to a socket, and the trick is that outputting socketInstance and socketInstance.connected to the console shows different results, what could be the problem?

the problem is that when refreshing the page, if the screen is smaller than the desktop one, it works fine, but if I open the page with a PC screen, then I don’t get data, apparently in the mobile version there are more renders, which is why everything works

```
App.tsx file
useEffect(() => {
        user && setSocketConnection(user?.id)
    }, [user])
```

```
socketInstance file
export let socketInstance: Socket

export const setSocketConnection = (userId: number) => {
    socketInstance = io(`${BASE_URL_SOCKET}`, {query: {userId}})
}
```

```
CustomHook for check connected.
const useSocketConnect = () => {
    const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(socketInstance?.connected)
    console.log(socketInstance)
    console.log(socketInstance?.connected)
    useEffect(() => {
        socketInstance?.on('connect', () => {
            setIsConnected(true)
        })
        socketInstance?.on('disconnect', () => {
            setIsConnected(false)
        })
        return () => {
            socketInstance?.off('connect')
            socketInstance?.off('disconnect')
        }
    }, [])
    return {isConnected}
}

export default useSocketConnect
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your question. To improve your post, could you [edit] the question by adding relevant information (detailed description of the problem, errors etc.). The errors logs should not be posted as images and also give your post a better title. The title how it's written now is too broad. :)

Comment: this is expected behaviour, "Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call console.log(), but it is the value of the object at the moment you open the console" from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: @Xiduzo I don’t understand if both comments are from you, but I’ll say that without a screen it would be impossible to understand, and I gave all the necessary information)) However, I still didn’t understand how to solve the problem ...

Comment: @node_modules i wrote above

Comment: @node_modules the problem is that when refreshing the page, if the screen is smaller than the desktop one, it works fine, but if I open the page with a PC screen, then I don’t get data, apparently in the mobile version there are more renders, which is why everything works